# Start mono application on startup

Tags: cron, mono, systemd-startup

This is my first time using a linux/rasbperry pie and I am trying to start a program I made in c# on my windows on startup. It has a graphical user interface, and can run from the command line using mono.

I have made a .sh script that runs from cronetab (startupprograms.sh) to try to run the commands that again run my program. I know the script runs, because I have made so that it also writes to an .err file and .log file.

I have tried to have different pieces of code in my .sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
 sleep 10
/usr/bin/mono "home/pi/Desktop/PictureViewer/Picture Viewer.exe"
```

Then I get an error: Unhandled Exception:

```
System.TypeInitilizationException: The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI" threw and exception. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Could not open display (X-Server required. Check your DISPLAY environment variable)
```

I also tried:

```
export DISPLAY:=0.0 %% /usr/bin/mono "home/pi/Desktop/PictureViewer/Picture Viewer.exe"
```

but then I get the same System.TypeInitializationException.

I also tried:

```
lxterminal -e /usr/bin/mono "home/pi/Desktop/PictureViewer/Picture Viewer.exe"
```

Then I get an error: `lxterminal:863 Gtk-Warning **: 22:29:26:658: cannot open display:`

I also tried to run the "`startx`" coupled with one of the other commands above, in the graphical user interface unaware of what it was doing, and that made my rasberry hang, and because of it was I unable to login into the user graphical UI again until I had deleted some .authorization files.

I also tried to use the rc.local but was unsuccessful there as well.

Typing `/usr/bin/mono or mono "home/pi/Desktop/PictureViewer/Picture Viewer.exe"`in the terminal will run the program just fine.

Comment: it's not `pie` .

Comment: graphical stuff is sometimes easiest integrated into your desktop manager instead.  https://superuser.com/a/146487/1608981

Comment: @Abel I will look into this. Do you have any pointers? Me being completely new to rasberry PI, and linux I don't know if I just do a simple small mistake or need to take a completely different approach. Will I have to make an SSH client that isn't graphical that SSH's into the rasberry itself and starts the application? *laugh*